# What are the cells of a simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

I am trying to understand a bit the concept of CW complexes. It seems that simplicial commplexes are cell complexes as well. I would have said intuitively that in that case, the cells $e_{\alpha}$ are  the interior of the simplices $Int (\sigma)$ of the simplicial complexes. But in Munkres' book I understand that that the cells $e_\alpha$ are union of open simplices. Which one is correct?

---

> We now see how strong the analogy is between the homology of simplicial
>   complexes and the homology of CW complexes. Let use introduce some
>   terminology that will make the analogy even stronger.   For each open
>   p-cell $e_{\alpha}$ of the CW complex X, the group
>   $H_p(\bar{e_{\alpha}}, \dot{e_{\alpha}})$ is infinite cyclic. The two
>   generators of this group will be called the two orientations of
>   $e_{\alpha}$. An oriented p-cell of X is an open p-cell $e_{\alpha}$
>   together with an orientation of $e_{\alpha}$. The cellular chain group
>   $D_p(X)=H_p(X^p,X^{p-1})$ is a free abelian group. One obtains a basis
>   for it by orienting each open p-cell $e_{\alpha}$ of $X$ and passing
>   to the corresponding element of $H_p(X^p,X^{p-1})$. [That is, by
>   taking the image of the orientation under the homomorphism induced by
>   inclusion $H_p(\bar{e_{\alpha}}, \dot{e_{\alpha}}) \to
> > H_p(X^p,X^{p-1}).$]
>
> The homology of the chain complex $D(X)$ is isomorphic, by our
>   theorem, with the singular homology of X.   In the special case where
>   $X$ is a triangulable CW-complex triangulated by a complex $K$, and
>   $H_p$ denotes simplicial homology, we interpret these comments as
>   follows : The fact that $X^p$ and $X^{p-1}$ are subcomplexes of $K$
>   implies that each open p-cell $e_{\alpha}$ is a union of open simplices of $K$, so that $\bar{e_{\alpha}}$  is the polytope of a subcomplex of
>   $K$. The group $H_p(\bar{e_{\alpha}}, \dot{e_{\alpha}})$ equals the
>   group of p-chains carried by $\dot{e_{\alpha}}$. This group is infinite
>   cyclic; either generator of this group is called a fundamental cycle
>   for $(\bar{e_{\alpha}}, \dot{e_{\alpha}})$.

Why the cells are union of open simplices and not just open simplices? I don't really get what the fundamental cycles are.

Comment: I thought a simplex was just a specific choice of cell type. You could also choose cubical cells, for example.

Comment: *are union of open simplices* This sounds, somewhat, like a simplicial complex.  I think the individual simplices are also required to satisfy additional requirements on their position, e.g. that their intersections are simplices or are empty.  i'm an amateur at homology though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: It would help if you provided the exact quote from Munkres.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in this quote where it says that "the cells $e_\alpha$ are union of open simplices".

Comment: Thanks, I edited

Comment: What is the precise definition of a  triangulable CW-complex?

Answer (score 1):

Munkres considers a *triangulable CW-complex* $X$. This means that you have

1. a CW-structure $\mathfrak C$ on $X$ with open cells $e_\alpha^n$ (where $n$ indicates the dimension of the cell)
2. a triangulation $K$ of $X$ with (compact) simplices $\sigma_\beta^n$

The open simplices $s_\beta^n \subset\sigma_\beta^n$ give us a CW-structure $\mathfrak C'$ on $X$, but there is no reason why $\mathfrak C = \mathfrak C'$. As an example consider $S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$ with the CW-structure $\mathfrak C$ given by the two open cells $p =\{(0,1)\},S^1 \setminus \{p\}$  and the triangulation $K$ given by the six simplices 
$$p, q =\{(1,0)\},-q, A = \{(x,y) \in S^1 \mid x \ge 0, y \ge 0 \}, B = \{(x,y) \in S^1 \mid x \ge 0, y \le 0 \}, \\C = \{(x,y) \in S^1 \mid x \le 0 \} .$$

Now it seems that Munkres considers triangulations of a special kind which is indicated by "The fact that $X^p$ and $X^{p−1}$ are subcomplexes of $K$ ..." As an example that this is not always true consider again $S^1$ with $\mathfrak C$ and the triangulation $L$ given by the six simplices 
$$-p, q,-q, D = \{(x,y) \in S^1 \mid x \le 0, y \ge 0 \}, E= \{(x,y) \in S^1 \mid x \le 0, y \le 0 \}, \\F = \{(x,y) \in S^1 \mid x \ge 0 \} .$$
Then the $0$-skeleton of $S^1$ is not a subcomplex of $L$.

However, under Munkres' assumption we can easily verify that each open $p$-cell of $X$ is a union of open simplices of $K$ (but in general not an open simplex of $K$ as shown by the above example).

If each $X^p$ is triangulated by a subcomplex $K^p$ of $K$, then $X^p$ is the union of all open simplices of $K^p$ and $X^{p-1}$ is the union of all open simplices of $K^{p-1}$. Hence $X^p \setminus X^{p-1}$ is the union of all open simplices $s_\beta$ of $K^p$ which do not belong to $K^{p-1}$. Now $X^p \setminus X^{p-1}$ is the union of the open $p$-cells $e^p_\alpha$ of $X$ which are pairwise disjoint and connected. Since each $s_\beta$ is connected, it is contained in a unique $e^p_\alpha$. This proves the above claim.